# Most efficient way for worker processes without pipes

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

In Python 3.6 (Ubuntu), I have 32 worker processes that I want to use best in order to utilize all CPU cores. The processes should each perform an operation based on a large numpy array.

I think the straight forward way is to use multiprocessing pipes:

```
# Using a classic multi processing pool structure:
for c in range(cycles):
   for pipe in process_pipes:
      pipe[0].send(numpy_data)
```

Which works fine, but the overhead cost are quite huge. I now use a different approach, which is faster:

```
def pool_init(ab):
    global buffer_shared
    buffer_shared = ab

buffer_shared_base = mp.Array(ctypes.c_float, BUFFER_SHARED_SIZE)
buffer_shared = np.ctypeslib.as_array(buffer_shared_base.get_obj())
buffer_shared = buffer_shared.reshape(num_processes, BUFFER_SHARED_SIZE)

pool = mp.Pool(initializer=pool_init, initargs=(buffer_shared, ), processes=num_processes)

for c in range(cycles):
   # chunk_size is the numpy data size for each process
   buffer_shared[:, 0:chunk_size] = NEW_DATA
   for pipe in pipes:
      pipe[0].send(True)
```

The main idea is to use shared memory to transmit the data and just use the pipe to transfer the start signal. This is considerably faster, probably because the numpy array does not have to be pickled.

Since this solution still feels cumbersome to me, can you tell me what you think the optimal (=lowest overhead) way for this kind of setup would be?

Comment: Why not use a multiprocess Queue ? https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue

Comment: I need to ensure that the n'th submit reaches the n'th process, as the processes contain state. Hence I need one submit queue per process which turned out to be slower.

Comment: What do you use your `pool`for? Where are the `pipes`defined. This example is not runnable and therefore it is very hard to help.

Comment: The pool was used to spawn the processes. I now ended up not using the pool, just multiple processes with `mp.Process` that are persistent and have a `queue` each. This seems to be fastest!